# Conditionally render a a background image based on current view using React Router

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I have set a background image on a parent component. when I route to a child component within the parent I do not want to see this background image, any ideas?

my app.js render code is:

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
        <Route path="/Welcome" component={Welcome} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: try to add  backgroundImage to Login Component

Comment: If i add in login component its applying as div, not applying for entire page

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try this ? ```return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App" >
            <Switch>
             <Route exact path="/" component={()=> (
                  <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }}>
                    <Login />
                  </div>)
               } />

             <Route path="/Welcome" component={Welcome}/>

           </Switch>
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>

  );```

Comment: Working perfect..!

Answer (score 2):

This one from @blueseal is working fine.

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          component={() => (
            <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }}>
              <Login />{' '}
            </div>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/Welcome" component={Welcome} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Why do you have two `.App` divs, one inside the other? Also, you should have asked @blueseal to post his comment as an answer.

Comment: It would likely be better to just put the `div.App` inside your `Login` component, rather than wrapping it inside your `Route`.

Comment: well, OP can give `className=App2` instead of `App`, then manage the `style` for the class `App2`. I just posted that as a comment OP can figure out to adjust the styles

Answer (score 1):

use this.props.location.pathname to get the current route as a string.

use this to conditionally render the background image in you inline style object like this

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App" style={{ this.props.location.pathname !== "/" && backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }}>
            <Switch>
             <Route path="/" component={Login} exact/>
             <Route path="/Welcome" component={Welcome}/>
           </Switch>
        </div> 
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if user is loggedin

```
style={{ backgroundImage: loggedIn ? `url(${bg})` : 'none' }}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do it in this way

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <div className="App" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bg})` }}>
          <Route path="/" component={Login} exact />
        </div>
        <div className="App">
          <Route path="/Welcome" component={Welcome} />
        </div>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: Only the image is appearing not even the page contents are displaying